# SpriteKit: detect if UILongPressGestureRecognizer tapped child node

Tags: swift, swift3, sprite-kit, uigesturerecognizer, swift4

I want to detect whether my node was tapped or not. I am using UIGestureRecognizer:

```
    let longPress = UILongPressGestureRecognizer()
    longPress.minimumPressDuration = CFTimeInterval(0.0)
    longPress.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.longPressGesture(longpressGest:)))
    self.view?.addGestureRecognizer(longPress)
```

And the function that is called:

```
@objc func longPressGesture(longpressGest: UIGestureRecognizer) {

    let touchPos = longpressGest.location(in: self.view)
    if atPoint(touchPos).name == "jump" {
        print("jump")
    } 

}
```

My button which I want to be detected when it is tapped:

```
let jump = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Any")
jump = CGSize(width: self.size.width*0.06, height: self.size.height*0.08)
jump = CGPoint(x: self.size.width*0.05 - self.size.width/2, y: self.size.height*0.1 - self.size.height/2)
jump.zPosition = 2
jump.name = "jump"
cameraNode.addChild(jump)
```

**Importend**: jump is a child node from my cameraNode

My cameraNode:

```
self.camera = cameraNode
self.addChild(cameraNode)

let cameraNode = SKCameraNode()
let range = SKRange(constantValue: 0)
let cameraConstraint = SKConstraint.distance(range, to: player)
cameraNode.constraints = [cameraConstraint]
```

With this code "jump" isn't printed. I think I have to convert the touchPos to the same coordinate system like the cameraNodes or jump buttons system. **My question: How can I convert view coordinates to my cameraNodes coordinate system?**

P.S. I already tried the whole convert functions which didn't work. Maybe I just did it wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SKNodes have a method called `convertPoint`

```
@objc func longPressGesture(longpressGest: UIGestureRecognizer) {

    let touchPosinView = longpressGest.location(in: self.view)
    let touchPos = self.convertPoint(fromView:touchPosinView )
    if atPoint(touchPos).name == "jump" {
        print("jump")
    } 

}
```

Comment: If I do this. This error message appears: **Cannot convert value of type 'SKView?' to expected argument type 'CGPoint'**

Comment: I think I already tried this but like this `convertPoint(fromView:longpressGest.location(in: self.view))` Is there a difference between this and that what you wrote?